# Table Snippets in Google Search - how to display table from my website in Google search results?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, rich-snippets, schema.org

At the moment I am working on website selling products online. Site has pages displaying product lists in form of tables. The markup of product list is actually HTML table.

I have noticed that some sites have tabular data displayed in Google search results. For example, W3Schools website.

I have figured out that it's called Table Snippets. But what should I do to get the Table Snippet for my site to be displayed in Google search results? I have tried to look for answer in Google but couldn't find anything useful.

I was thinking of implementing Schema.org Itemlist or multiple Schema.org Product items (for each product on the page), adding metadata to page so Google could find correct product data but I am not sure if I achieve what I want with Schema.org . Am I thinking in right direction? Or I must try anything different to get the table in search results? I just want some hint.

P.S. Not sure if this is important, but just in case. Website is ASP.NET (WebForms).

Comment: Re. the duplicate: this question does not seem to be about Google Sitelinks.